# Show that $\int e^{ix}\mathrm d x=\frac{1}{i}e^{ix}+C$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that $$\int_a^b e^{ix}\mathrm d x=\frac{1}{i}e^{ix}+C$$
for $a,b\in\mathbb R$. To simplify, I'll suppose that $a=-1$ and $b=1$. I tried to integrate over $\Gamma=[i,-i]\cup \{e^{i\theta}\mid \theta\in[-\pi,\pi]\}$. Then, I get,

$$0=\int_\Gamma e^zdz=\int_{-1}^1 e^{-2i t+i}(-2i)dt+\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{e^{i\theta}}\theta e^{i\theta}d\theta,$$

and thus,
$$\int_{-1}^1e^{2it}dt=\frac{1}{2ie^i}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i\theta}\theta e^{i\theta}d\theta,$$
but this last integral looks complicate to compute. Any idea ?

Comment: Derive the right-hand side and compare with the integrand

Comment: You have a definite integral, it wouldn't have $C$ and $x$ in R.H.S.

Comment: Why do you mix defined and undefined integrals ?

Comment: $e^{cx}dx=e^ydy/c$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_a^b e^{ix}dx=\int_a^b\cos xdx+i\int_a^b \sin xdx$$
$$=\sin b-\sin a - i\cos b+i\cos a$$
$$=\frac{1}{i}\left(\cos b+i\sin b -\cos a-i\sin a\right)$$
$$=\frac{e^{ib}-e^{ia}}{i}$$